# Scrapy - Following relative urls with LinkExtractor and Rule

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, scrapy

[This](https://auto.ndtv.com/classifieds/default/apply-elastic-filter?Classified_page=1) is the ajax request that I start crawling. It has the pagination links at the bottom of the source code like this. The urls are relative, so I couldn't figure out how to use `Rule` and `LinkExtractor` here.

`<li class='pagination__item selected'><button class='pagination__link btn btn-xs' type='button'>1</button></li><li class='pagination__item'><button class='pagination__link btn btn-xs custom-js-paging' data-href=/classifieds/default/apply-elastic-filter?Classified_page=2 type='button'>2</button></li>`

This is my crawler's code. Obviously, the `Rule` is not working as intended. `LinkExtractor` probably matching the relative url though. What I wanted is; the crawler converts the relative urls to absolute url if it is possible and follows the extracted links from the pagination.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = [
        'https://auto.ndtv.com/classifieds/default/apply-elastic-filter?Classified_page=1',
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/classifieds/default/apply-elastic-filter?Classified_page=\d+',)), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        items = response.css('div.usedcar-widget a.usedcar-widget__link::attr(href)').getall()

        if items:
            for item in items:
                if item.startswith('/used/'):
                    yield scrapy.Request(
                        url='https://auto.ndtv.com{}'.format(item),
                        method='GET',
                        callback=self.parse_items,
                    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        # scraping items
```

Answer (score 0):

The `allow` parameter of `LinkExtractor` is a regular expression or a list of regular expressions.

`?` has a special meaning in a regular expression, so your filter is not working as you think it is. It’s not the only special character in your string, but that one is definitely messing up your intentions.

You can either use Python’s `re.escape` to automatically convert your plain text string into an equivalent regular expression, or manually modify your string to escape characters that are special characters in regular expressions.